# Calculating rotation in angles for planes in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-rotation

For a reference I am attaching two image `A` and `B`
[image: Planes]

I want to calculate the rotation of Image `B` assuming you know all the dimensions of Image `A` in Opencv

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of the rotated rectangle in B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a projection plane. So, you will get a perspective projection. And then you can resolve the transformation matrix variables to get the angle. Hope this helps, lemme know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks @Vicky Budhiraja I need your assistance bro...Please help me out with code or atleast some reference...

Comment: Actually I am working on Head pose estimation with frames of videos...I am using AIshaks transparent overlay to overlay Image on to face with cvwarpperspective...But now it works only for say 30 degree of head rotation so I need to start of with Head pose Detection and overlay image...Please Vicky Help me out with this...

Comment: After looking your sample images and the problem you just mentioned about 'head pose detection' it seems you already have the features. Are you trying to use the feature tracking method? In that case Affine transformation works well in subsequent frames. Tracking of features within frames is a good method, apart from this 'snaking' is another old and good method. There are other methods too! So, it depends what is the complexity of video. Yes, I believe the content of the video should be the deciding factor as it drives the accuracy. Lemme know! :)

Comment: I already Have the feature of head pose estimation and overlay of object but it does not work after certain rotation...

Comment: When you say, it doesn't work after certain rotation(s), what do you mean. If you can be in a little detail instead of giving out some clues, I will be able to help you in a better way. OR you are looking for only the code? I don't have the code for this, but once the idea is clear writing code should be easy in languages like MATLAB or C++ So, send more details! :)